# Conditional cases expression

Tags: conditionals

How can I create a command `\if` with 1 argument, namely `#1`,

```
\if{#1=1}{symbol1}...{#1=n}{symboln}
```

that returns `symbol1`, when `#1` is `1`, ..., and returns `symboln`, when `#1` is `n`, and returns nothing, when `#1` isn't `1,...,n`?

For example, I'd like to use the command

```
\if{#1=1}{\mapsto}{#1=2}{\mapsfrom}{#1=3}{\rightarrow}
```

when I'm defining a larger command.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: @Thorsten: OK, won't greet unnecessarily anymore. However, I don't know what "sign your questions" means, I didn't sign anything.

Comment: Well I just took one of our text building blocks from http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/430/3240

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For simple integer comparisons, TeX provides `\ifcase`:

```
\ifcase<integer>
  % Case 0
\or
  % Case 1
\or
...
\else
  % Optional
\fi
```

So you can define a wrapper such as

```
\newcommand\myswitch[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    \ValueWasZero
  \or
    \ValueWasOne
  \or
    \ValueWasTwo
  ...
  \else
     \OtherCases
  \fi
}
```

Here, you start from the 0 case and work upward: often you'll see `\ifcase#1\relax\or` with no 0 case at all. You can use as many `\or` statements as you like, depending on how many numbers you need. The `\else` is optional, and is used if you want 'otherwise do this' functionality.

By the way, don't define `\if`: this is a TeX primitive which you *should not change*!

Comment: hmm, I don't really understand what's going on. You can assume that #1 is always an integer and assume that symbol1...symboln are latex symbols, such as "\mapsto", "\rightarrow", and so on. I was expecting \newcommand{\if}{...} as your answer. Could you give me an example of how to use the command?

Comment: Oh and another comment, this command "if" that I'm asking for, is primarily meant to be used when defining larger commands, so I don't have to copy paste them, since they are going to be almost identical.

Comment: @Leon: Does the edit help?

Comment: Yes, it's working! For others that might read this, my example from the original question would be witten `\ifcase #1 \or \mapsto \or \mapsfrom \or \rightarrow \else \fi`. For example `\ifcase 2 \or \mapsto \or \mapsfrom \or \rightarrow \else \fi` returns \mapsfrom. Thank you, @Joseph Wright.

Answer (score 16):

Using `\ifcase` as Joseph Wright suggested is the best way most the time.

An alternative which might have benefits for some applications would be to define a set of macros which names dependent on the number. Using `\csname ...\endcsname` or `\@namedef` macro names can contain numbers or these can be converted to a Roman number using `\romannumeral`. Then `\@nameuse` can be used to use these macros. The `etoolbox` package also provides the identical user-level macros `\csdef` and `\csuse`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\defcase[1]{\@namedef{mycase@\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\newcommand\myswitch[1]{\@nameuse{mycase@\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\makeatother

% or alternatively:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\defcase[1]{\@namedef{mycase@\romannumeral#1}}
\newcommand\myswitch[1]{\@nameuse{mycase@\romannumeral#1}}
\makeatother

% Define cases:
\defcase{0}{code for case 0}
\defcase{1}{code for case 1}
\defcase{2}{code for case 2}
\defcase{3}{...}

\begin{document}
% Usage
\myswitch{1}
% \myswitch{some integer expression}

\end{document}
```

The use of the eTeX primitive `\numexpr` makes the whole thing a little more robust to fancy user input.