# How to select conditional text?

Tags: xetex, conditionals, xifthen

I've three variable statements :

- Statement1 = You are Great Student.
- Statement2 = You are average Student.
- Statement3 = You Need improvement on list of topics mentioned below.

In the report card for student, I want to show one of this statement based on marks scored by the student [I'm reading marks from external csv file as `\markscore`]

- If value of `\markscore` is greater than or equal to 90 i want to print
  Statement1
- If value of `\markscore` is greater than or equal to 80 but less than
  90 i want to print Statement2
- Else I want to print Statement3 in the report card.

Can you please suggest latex package to print statements conditionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a package:

```
\ifnum\markscore>89
statement 1
\else
\ifnum\markscore>79
statement 2
\else
statement 3
\fi
\fi
```

Comment: Well, the 'official' LaTeX way is to use `ifthen`, but you knew that ;-)

Comment: Thank You Sir for reply. While excuting tex file using xelatex ; i'm getting warnings mentioned below: ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.334 }

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.334 }

?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.334 }

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.334 }

Comment: In that case `\markscore` does not expand to an integer. I had to guess as you did not provide a real example document. Joseph did the same,

Comment: Thank You Sir. I've updated my CSV to store only integers and now warning is gone.

Answer (score 7):

The 'official' way to do this is to use a package: traditionally `ifthen` but perhaps now you [might choose `etoolbox` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete). I'll use `ifthen`, which here works reasonably clearly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\markscore}{90} % For testing
\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\markscore<80}
  {You need improvement on list of topics mentioned below}
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\markscore<90}
      {You are average student}
      {You are great student}%
  }%
\end{document}
```

You could of course use the same logic as in [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136039) and have the flow of statements perhaps a little clearer.

Comment: Tbh my first reaction to the OP was `\ifnum`. So i, personally, would stick to DCs answer. I guess you aimed at the `\ifnumless` macro by bringing `etoolbox` into play. Therewith http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/placing-many-conditionals-in-a-series/36202#36202 maybe is intereresting here.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Somehow I'm getting warning mentioned below (while executing using xelatex) : (similar to one without package)! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.333 }

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.333 }

?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.333 }

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.333 }

?

Comment: @PawanMude Are you trying exactly what I've put? If not, please detail what you've changed: if it's a big change then a new linked question might be best.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, for your comments and sharing linked post. Somehow after making few changes in my code option mentioned by David is working without warning. I'll analyze it further.