# pgfmathsetmacro not working

Tags: pgfmath

Why is this not working please:

```
\newcommand\bareme[1]
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{5}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{8}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{7}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{9}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{1}{}}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\points}{\bareme{1}}
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please always post full minimal examples that others can test as is. Here we have to add a lot of stuff before this even have a chance of compiling. If it is always handling numbers, `\ifthenelse` is probably overkill.

Comment: If you're only doing integer comparison, could https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17678/ be useful?

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with your code is that you are not using the correct syntax. If you look section 89.3.5 of the current [pgf manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (version 3.0.1a), then you will find that pgf provides a `\pgfmathifthenelse{x}{y}{z}` command that you use inside `\pgfmathparse`, or `\pgfmathsetmacro`, as the function `ifthenelse(x,y,z)`. So, your code is using the syntax for the standalone macro `\pgfmathifthenelse` whereas you *should* be using the code for the internal `ifthenelse` pgfmath function. Further, the example given in the manual for `ifthenelse` is

```
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(5==4,"yes","no")} \pgfmathresult
```

so your use of `\equal{...}` is incorrect and unnecessary.

Secondly, to me it seems a bad idea to define a macro that you then give to `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Instead I would make your macro set `\points` directly:

```
\newcommand\bareme[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\points}{ifthenelse(#1==1,5,
     ifthenelse(#1==2, 8,
        ifthenelse(#1==3, 7,
          ifthenelse(#1==4, 9,
            ifthenelse(#1==5, 1,"")))))}%
}
```

This certainly works. On the other hand, there is a much simpler way to do what you want using the TeX `\ifcase` command:

```
\newcommand\Bareme[1]{%
  \ifcase #1\or 5% have to skip 0
    \or 8%
    \or 7%
    \or 9%
    \or 1%
    \else ?%
  \fi%
}
```

For completeness, here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand\bareme[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\points}{ifthenelse(#1==1,5,
     ifthenelse(#1==2, 8,
        ifthenelse(#1==3, 7,
          ifthenelse(#1==4, 9,
            ifthenelse(#1==5, 1,"")))))}%
}

\newcommand\Bareme[1]{%
  \ifcase #1\or 5% have to skip 0
    \or 8%
    \or 7%
    \or 9%
    \or 1%
    \else ?%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
    \bareme{1} \points

    \Bareme{1}
    \Bareme{2}
    \Bareme{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think OP is using `ifthen` package but your answer still holds.

Comment: @percusse As the OP didn't provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it's not clear but I thought that they were using `pgf` because they are using `\pgfmathsetmacro`. On the other hand, perhaps they are using `ifthen` and the use of `\pgfmathsetmacro` is the source of confusion...

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `\ifthenelse{\equal{1}{#1}}{A}{B}` is a set of instructions for *printing* either A or B, but doesn't produce the result in a form that `\pgfmathsetmacro` is happy with (it's not *fully expandable*).

If the legal input are integers from 1 to 5, you can use an array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand*{\baremeoutput}{{5,8,7,9,1}}
\newcommand*{\bareme}[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\points}{\baremeoutput[#1-1]}%
}

\begin{document}

\bareme{1}\points

\bareme{2}\points

\bareme{3}\points

\bareme{4}\points

\bareme{5}\points

\end{document}
```

Since PGF arrays start from zero, one has to shift the index.

A different approach with `expl3`, that can work also with non consecutive indices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bareme}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nf \points
   {
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
     {
      {1}{5}
      {2}{8}
      {3}{7}
      {4}{9}
      {5}{1}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\bareme{1}\points

\bareme{2}\points

\bareme{3}\points

\bareme{4}\points

\bareme{5}\points

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote always my friends :-). Hi, +1 for you and Andrew,