# Allowed Algebra with \the\year

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I have a homework problem that I reuse relatively frequently, and I'm trying to update the solution to match the dynamic.

Suppose `z(t)` is a periodic function with period 3. Evaluate `z(\the\year)`.

```
\begin{array}{c||c|c|c|c|c|c}
    t   &0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dotsb & \the\year\\
    \hline
    z(t)    &12 & 5\pi & -6 & 12 & \dotsb & ??
\end{array}
```

Is there any clever coding that can be used to automatically compute `\the\year` mod3 and `\ifthenelse` the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with it outputting `-1` instead of `2`, then you can use TeX primitives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\modcomp[2]{\the\numexpr #1 - (#1/#2)*#2\relax}

\begin{document}
10 mod 3 is \modcomp{10}{3}. 11 mod 3 is \modcomp{11}{3}.  

\the\year\ mod 7 is \modcomp{\the\year}{7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you insist on non-negative outputs, the TeX primitive `\divide ... by` truncates rather than rounds, so you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\b
\newcount\n
\newcommand\modcomp[2]{\n=#1 \b=#2 \divide\n by \b \multiply\n by \b \the\numexpr#1 - \number\n\relax}

\begin{document}
10 mod 3 is \modcomp{10}{3}. 11 mod 3 is \modcomp{11}{3}.  

\the\year\ mod 7 is \modcomp{\the\year}{7}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a nice solution, @willie-wong and then I can use `\ifthenelse` on that result.

Comment: I just added a version with non-negative values. I forgot you were going to do `\ifthenelse`. With the non-negative output you can use `\ifcase` instead which has easier syntax than `\ifthenelse` for this application. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17678/119

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX (instead of either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX), you can perform modular division on `\the\year`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
% helper macro '\modulo' invokes Lua to perform the actual job
\newcommand\modulo[2]{\luaexec{tex.sprint(#1 \% #2)}}

\begin{document}
\the\year, \modulo{\the\year}{3}
\end{document}
```